# How to ignore text in the same div but different class in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract date from the website. html code is as follows

```
<div class="tcell" style="width:175px;">
 <!-- status icon and date -->
 <a name="post6425787"><img alt="Old" class="inlineimg" src="https://www.f150forum.com/images/statusicon/post_old.gif"/></a>
                    12-10-2019, 06:13 PM

                    <!-- / status icon and date -->
 </div>,
 <div class="tcell">Smawgunner</div>,
 <div class="tcell" style="width:175px;">
 <!-- status icon and date -->
 <a name="post6425799"><img alt="Old" class="inlineimg" src="https://www.f150forum.com/images/statusicon/post_old.gif"/></a>
                    12-10-2019, 06:18 PM

                    <!-- / status icon and date -->
 </div>,
 <div class="tcell">CKsBAT</div>
```

I want to extract only date by ignoring name fields. My code is as follows

```
date = posts.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'div' and 
                                   tag.get('class') == ['tcell'])
for i in date:
    print(i.text)
```

The above code gives both Date as well as name. How would I get only date from the HTML code? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most directly, you can use `select` and `:nth-child(odd)`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

html = """
<div>
  <div class="tcell" style="width:175px;">
    <a name="post6425787">
      <img alt="Old" 
           class="inlineimg" 
           src="https://www.f150forum.com/images/statusicon/post_old.gif"
      />
    </a>
                       12-10-2019, 06:13 PM
  </div>,
  <div class="tcell">Smawgunner</div>,

  <div class="tcell" style="width:175px;">
    <a name="post6425799">
      <img alt="Old" 
           class="inlineimg" 
           src="https://www.f150forum.com/images/statusicon/post_old.gif"
      />
    </a>
                     12-10-2019, 06:18 PM
  </div>,
  <div class="tcell">CKsBAT</div>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

for x in soup.select("div.tcell:nth-child(odd)"):
    print(x.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
12-10-2019, 06:13 PM
12-10-2019, 06:18 PM
```

If you need precision based on the nature of the contents, you can use a regex that matches your date format exactly (surrounded by nothing but whitespace; loosen the regex as needed):

```
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
pattern = r"^\s*(\d\d-){2}\d{4}, \d\d:\d\d [AP]M\s*$"

for x in soup.find_all(text=re.compile(pattern)):
    print(x.strip())
```

If your date format is uncertain and you want to grab anything that can be parsed as a date:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as parse_date

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

def try_parse_date(s):
    try: return parse_date(s, fuzzy=True)
    except ValueError: pass

for x in soup.find_all(text=try_parse_date):
    print(x.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<div class="tcell" style="width:175px;">
 <!-- status icon and date -->
 <a name="post6425787"><img alt="Old" class="inlineimg" src="https://www.f150forum.com/images/statusicon/post_old.gif"/></a>
                    12-10-2019, 06:13 PM

                    <!-- / status icon and date -->
 </div>,
 <div class="tcell">Smawgunner</div>,
 <div class="tcell" style="width:175px;">
 <!-- status icon and date -->
 <a name="post6425799"><img alt="Old" class="inlineimg" src="https://www.f150forum.com/images/statusicon/post_old.gif"/></a>
                    12-10-2019, 06:18 PM

                    <!-- / status icon and date -->
 </div>,
 <div class="tcell">CKsBAT</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("div", {'class': 'tcell'}):
    item = item.get_text(strip=True)
    if item[0].isdigit():
        print(item)
```

Output:

```
12-10-2019, 06:13 PM
12-10-2019, 06:18 PM
```

> Note that you can use if `PM` or `AM` for more specific :)

Comment: Few other names have strings starting with digits it is considering even that in the result.

Comment: @anonymous13 that's why i left note to use `PM` and `AM`

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
date = soup.select('div.tcell>a')
for d in date:
   print(d.parent.text.strip())
```